# Java HashSet contains method return true when it supposes to be false

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I define a `Triple` class with `equals` and `hashcode` method. According the docs,`HashSet.contains()` method of Java HashSet must returns the same value of `Objects.equals()`. But `contains()` method of Java HashSet method return true, when it suppose to be false.

```java
class Triple{

    private List<Integer> triple;

    public Triple(int one, int two, int three){
        this.triple = new ArrayList<>();
        this.triple.add(one);
        this.triple.add(two);
        this.triple.add(three);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return triple.get(0).hashCode() + triple.get(1).hashCode() + triple.get(2).hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object t){
        Triple triple = (Triple)t;
        return triple.triple.contains(this.triple.get(0))
                && triple.triple.contains(this.triple.get(1))
                && triple.triple.contains(this.triple.get(2));
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Triple> answersSet = new HashSet<>();
        Triple triple1 = new Triple(-4,0,4);
        Triple triple2 = new Triple(0,0,0);
        answersSet.add(triple1);
        boolean b = answersSet.contains(triple2); //returns true
        b = Objects.equals(triple1,triple2); //but it returns false, 
    }
}
```

Comment: `triple1` does contain all of the values of `triple2`. It only contains `0`. Does `triple1` contain `0`? Yes. And that is all you test. Should it contain three `0`(s) to be equal? Arguably, yes.

Comment: By the way, `record Triple ( int x , int y , int z ){}` would eliminate all your problems. And using an IDE to convert that [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to a conventional class might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `equals` is broken. You only test if the value is contained in the `List`, not that the three values are equal. I think you wanted

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Triple t = (Triple) o;
    return triple.get(0).equals(t.triple.get(0))
            && triple.get(1).equals(t.triple.get(1))
            && triple.get(2).equals(t.triple.get(2));
}
```

Which (obviously) returns `false` with your example data. Also, you can simplify your constructor

```
public Triple(int one, int two, int three) {
    this.triple = List.of(one, two, three);
}
```

As discussed in the comments, and pointed out in other answers; your original issues were caused by a hashcode based on simple addition where all three values had the same sum. And your equals was broken because `a` could equal `b` without `b` equaling `a` (since `a` might contain one value that is present in `b`, while `b` might contain three values with only one of them present in `a`). It would probably be best to store the three values as `int` fields. You should also make the `Triple` immutable, since changing any field would alter the instance's hashcode. You might as well override `toString` and make it `Comparable` while you are at it. So the final version might look something like,

```
class Triple implements Comparable<Triple> {
    private final int a, b, c;

    public Triple(int one, int two, int three) {
        this.a = one;
        this.b = two;
        this.c = three;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return java.util.Objects.hash(this.a, this.b, this.c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Triple) {
            Triple that = (Triple) o;
            return this.a == that.a 
                    && this.b == that.b 
                    && this.c == that.c;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d, %d)", a, b, c);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Triple that) {
        int comp = Integer.compare(this.a, that.a);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        comp = Integer.compare(this.b, that.b);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        return Integer.compare(this.c, that.c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails to explain the results OP observes. For example, fails to explain how 0/0/0 and -4/0/4 have the same hashcode and are one-way equals, explaining the bizarre result where `hashSet.contains` says yes, but `a.equals(b)` says no.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I see you took care of those gaps with your answer. I also think I agree that it should have three `int` fields instead of a `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 4):

> boolean b = answersSet.contains(triple2); //returns true

It does, because both your `equals` method, as well as your `hashCode()` method, produce identical values here. At first glance, it doesn't look like it. But, really, this is what your code does. Let's go through it:

### hashCode

> return triple.get(0).hashCode() + triple.get(1).hashCode() + triple.get(2).hashCode();

The hashCode of an `Integer` value is simply.. itself. Thus, for `-4,0,4`, you end up with a hashCode of **0**. After all, -4 + 0 + +4 is 0.

The hashcode of the `0, 0, 0` is also **0**.

This is called a hash collision. It doesn't mean your implementation of `hashCode()` is definitely broken; it happens. By simple pigeon hole principle: There are 2^32 different possible hashcodes, and there are 2^96 different `Triple` instances; therefore, it **has** to be the case that at least 2^64 different `Triple` instances nevertheless have the same hashCode.

**This is fine** - nothing in the spec requires that different objects have different hashcodes. The spec dictates only two things:

- If 2 objects are equal they **must** have the same hashCode (your code does that right).
- If lots of different objects nevertheless hash to the same hashcode, the performance of hashset and hashmap and friends will be really bad. It'll work, though. Just, not very fast. This is called 'hash distribution'.

Your hash distribution is mostly fine. You could do a better job by taking the position of your numbers into account. Something like:

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
  return triple.get(0) + triple.get(1) * 31 + triple.get(2) * 97;
```

31 and 97 are prime numbers. That's intentional.

### equals

Your equals method is broken. It doesn't concern itself with order! It says that equality implies that the provided `Triple` object contains every value of `this` triple.

Given that `this` triple is 0/0/0, your checks if the `triple` passed in contains 0 (it does). Then it checks if it contains 0 (it.. still does), and then checks it a third time, which.. it still does.

This is really, really broken. It clashes with hashCode (0/0/0 and 5/0/4 are equal, but do not have the same hashCode, that's a violation), and is a bizarre definition of equality. It also isn't reversible, and equals methods have to be: if `a.equals(b)` is true, then `b.equals(a)` must also be true, but with 0/0/0 and -4/0/4 this isn't true either.

Separately, your equals method will throw a `ClassCastException` if you pass a non-triple to it, which is also broken. The documentation of equals describes what you have to do. You broke 3 of its rules.

Let's fix all of them:

The fix is to check each *position*:

```
@Override public  boolean equals(Object other) {
  if (other == null || other.getClass() != Triple.class) return false;
  Triple t = (Triple) other;
  return t.triple.get(0).equals(this.triple.get(0)) &&
    t.triple.get(1).equals(this.triple.get(1)) &&
    t.triple.get(2).equals(this.triple.get(2));
}
```

### or..

use records, or, [lombok's `@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) which takes care of all this for you:

```
public record Triple(int a, int b, int c) {}
```

or

```
@Value
public class Triple {
  List<Integer> triple;

  public Triple(int a, b, c) {
    this.triple = List.of(a, b, c);
  }
}
```

More generally it feels like this class should have 3 `int` typed fields instead of one `List<Integer>` typed one.

Answer (score 1):

For two lists to compare equally, each list must have the `same size` and `list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))` must be `true` for `0 <= i < List.size()`

This is easily achieved by the following:

- use the pattern matching `instanceof` (Java 16+) which casts and assigns `obj` to `t` if true.
- simply compare the lists using equals since lists override equals using the afore mentioned one-to-one comparisons.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Triple t) {
        return t.triple.equals(this.triple);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, you can create the `hashCode` as follows.

```
public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(triple.get(0), triple.get(1), triple.get(2));
}
```